# Displaying negative time labels on an Excel 2007chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

Negative time labels are displayed in this Microsoft Excel 2003 file:

[image: Graph in Excel 2003 shows negative time labels]

The same file opened with Excel 2007 does not display negative time labels:

[image: Graph in Excel 2007 does not show negative time labels]

The axis number format and the source data format is the same: [hh]:mm.

The "Calendar from 1904" option is set in both version.

Using the standard number format, negative labels are displayed:

[image]

How can I make Excel 2007 do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I answered my own question:

- Added a helper column with cumulated time as hours, formatted as a standard number:

  ```
  Date             | Accumulated time  | Accumulated time for the graphic
  August 13, 2007  | -00:03            | -0,05
  August 14, 2007  |  00:02            |  0,033333333
  August 16, 2007  |  00:29            |  0,483333333
  ```

  The formula for the helper column being `AccumulatedTime * 24` so `1` means one hour.

  Keep in mind the workbook must have the *Calendar from 1904* option set for negative time to be properly displayed. Otherwise, they'll show as a long string of `#`.
- Changed the source data column in the graphic.
- Set axis number format as `0":00"`. It works nicely if the axis unit is an hour or multiple hours, but not a fraction of an hour.

The solution is quite simple once I think of it, if not straightforward.
Hope this helps other people too!