# Excel 2013 chart with time values as axis units

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Have an Excel chart whose x axis units are time (hh:mm).

**Issue:** The x axis data range is -06:00 to +06:00. The negative axis labels do not display.

**What I have tried:**

1. Have changed the file to the 1907 date system.
2. Have tried altering all the axis variables but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Is this a calculated field or simply data? If the value is simply positive or negative hours, try formatting as a number rather than time. Excel should recognize that for your chart.

Answer (score 0):

See the post linked below for a workaround.  As far as I know, there is no direct way to solve this issue yet.

[Displaying negative time labels on an Excel 2007chart](https://superuser.com/questions/553428/displaying-negative-time-labels-on-an-excel-2007chart)